# Portuguese Language não é um site de língua portuguesa?

Tags: discussion, support

Existem algumas perguntas que devemos usar a língua inglesa para ajudar a compreensão dos estrangeiros, mas não estamos exagerando? Acho os usuários que se interessam pela língua portuguesa devem se acostumar com respostas escritas em português, por que não? Isso é a lógica natural?
Aqui no Meta, por exemplo, a maioria das perguntas e respostas estão em inglês.

Qual é o verdadeiro objetivo do site Portuguese Language? Pra onde estamos caminhando?

Portuguese Language não é um site de língua portuguesa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podes verificar na [ajuda do site](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) que a ideia é poderes perguntar nas duas línguas, mas sugere-se que se pergunte e responda em português.

No meta, tanto quanto sei deve-se escrever em inglês para que toda a gente possa compreender e discutir os assuntos do site e para facilitar a vida aos CM's da rede SE.

> Should I write in Portuguese or English?
>
> Both languages are accepted. If you are learning Portuguese, we
>   suggest that you learn by doing and ask in Portuguese, but there is no
>   obligation. When answering a question, we encourage you to answer in
>   the language of the question, if you are able. Don't worry about
>   making a few mistakes: other community members can help with
>   corrections if you are not as strong in that language.
>
> Note that some contributors prefer to answer in Portuguese, so you may
>   get replies in Portuguese. Posts made in only one language may be
>   translated into the other one by community members for wider
>   accessibility.
>
> On the main site, all tags should be in Portuguese unless there is no
>   Portuguese equivalent for a concept; then English is accepted. On the
>   meta site, tags should normally be in English.